# Итератор изменяет свое значения

Tags: c++, итераторы

Столкнулся с проблемой и никак не могу решить уже пару дней , прошу помощи. Суть в том , что мне необходимо из строки вычленить все цифры, разделенные там пробелами . Вот как я пытался это сделать :

```
string str = "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1";
int *arr =  new int;

string :: const_iterator it = str.begin();
// Если тут вывести (*it) то результатом будет 9
int i = 0;
for (; it != str.end(); ++it)
{
    if (isdigit(*it))
    {
        arr[i] = *it;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Как видно из комментария , на его месте разыменованный итератор возвращает 9 , ОДНАКО , когда итератор попадает в цикл , то :
1) в первый раз он проходит проверку isdigit(*it) и попадает дальше
2) в arr[0] по какой-то причине записываться не 9 , а 49 и с другими цифрами то же самое - их значение увеличивается.Функция stoi(*it) почему-то отказывается работать .

Comment: В `int *arr = new int;` есть место ровно под один `int`, так что `arr[i]` нормально работает только для `i == 0`. Почитайте про `std::vector`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat оно и для i == 0 не работает нормально. Я пробовал создавать и статический массив и динамический с разными размерами ( и без них в динамическом) , но результат при выводе массива один и тот же : 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int DESIRABLE_VALUE = 100;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1";

    int *arr = new int[DESIRABLE_VALUE];

    auto it = str.begin();

    int i = 0;
    for (; it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (isdigit(*it))
        {
            arr[i] = *it - 48;
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(auto i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

-48, чтобы перевести из ascii, т.к. в итератор итерирует по строке получая чары (а конкретно вы получаете номер числа в ascii таблице, то есть числу 9 будет соответствовать 57

И соответственно вы не выделили под ваш `arr` память с помощью оператора `[]`, в котором нужно было указать, сколько элементов соответствуещего типа будет в вашем динамическом массиве.

Вместо `constexpr int DESIRABLE_VALUE = 100;` вы можете сперва пройтись по массиву строк посчитав, сколько чисел в нем находится, чтобы позже выяснить, сколько памяти потребуется вашему `arr` для дальнейшей работы с полученными из строки числами.

Comment: Никогда в кодах не используйте эти магические цифры . С чего вы взяли, что нужно отнять 48?

Comment: @LexMarchenko Нет , вот вывод с моим условием : 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 . Даже если поменять все цифры( к примеру на "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" , все равно числа остаются точно такими же :49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, это магическое число было использовано для примера, спасбо что подметили, а касательно 48 - можете взглянуть на ascii таблицу сами, в конкретном случае человека, задавшего вопрос это является решением. Если не прав, поправьте - буду благодарен:)

Comment: @Max, все верно, т.к. в этом случае итератор берет каждый символ строки отдельно, сейчас добавлю решение, если числа состоят более чем из 1 цифры.

Comment: @Max, прошу прощение за не самый чистый и красивый код, быстро накидал: [туть](https://pastebin.com/a2iXmqbv)

Comment: @LexMarchenko Спасибо

Comment: @Lex Marchenko, а что, записать  arr[i] = *it -  '0';  намного сложнее, чем  arr[i] = *it - 48; ?  Только в первом случаи код выдаст правильный результат на всех машинах. И зачем использовать массив размера  намного превышающего количества элементов строки?   Достаточен размер str.size()

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не сложно, конечно, просто написал первое решение, которое пришло в голову. Мне более интересно, сложно ли Вам писать комментарии в нормальной манере или тяжелый день выдался на работе?
Касательно magic number я Вам сразу ответил, Ваше решение с str.size() тоже не самое лучшее и с ним можно поспорить. В любом случае, хорошего Вам дня.

Comment: интересно, а где вы видели  ненормальную манеру? Если вы программируете, то такие простые вещи должны быть привычкой.  Я говорю о хорошей манере программирования, а вы говорите о моих манерах, а это значит, что вы критикуете меня, а я критиковал лишь ваш код. Так что стоит подумать  кому из нас стоит корректировать манеры.  И вам доброй ночи, и  старайтесь критику воспринять как помощь, а не как оскарбление. В любом случаи я такой код не могу не отмечать минусом...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я полностью согласен с Вашей критикой, она уместна и верна, я ценю любую критику. Имхо, как мне показалось, выглядело это именно как попытка возмутится, а не покритиковать. Если не правильно понял, извиняйте) Всем добра.